# How to create an optional foreign key to another table, using custom column names, with fluent api?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, fluent-entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 5, and I am writing code-first models that I wish to use on top of an existing database schema. So, I have no control over the schema design.

I have two tables, `matters` and `users`. The `users` table contains user accounts - actual users of the system. The `matters` table contains data similar to like an scheduled appointment, or something of that nature.

The `matters` table has a foreign key to `users`, in a column named `manager`. This column just says "hey, this `users` row specifies the `manager` of this `matter`." This is an optional key - a matter does not have to have a manager.

The model for the records in `users` does not need a property that maps back to these matters.

My current attempt at the mapping looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Matter>().HasOptional(m => m.ProjectManager).WithRequired().Map(m => m.MapKey("project_manager"));
```

With that, I am trying to say that `Matter` has an optional FK, on the model's `ProjectManager` property, and that the user is required to exist, and that the column name, in the `matters` table is called `project_manager`.

This isn't working though, and the generated SQL is incorrect, but I can't figure out how to get what I'm looking for. If I were to write the SQL it'd look something like this

```
SELECT matters.*, users.*
FROM matters
LEFT JOIN users ON matters.project_manager = users.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do to get that sql is the following thing.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Matter>()
.HasOptional(m => m.ProjectManager)
.WithMany(u => u.Matters)
.HasForeinKey(k=>k.project_manager);
```

This code should generate the sql statement that you are looking for.
There is a nice tool that generates the code first tables and fluent api configuration, it is the [EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838), this was very helpfull for me.